# How to make serverStatus() query via spring data in mongoDb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, monitoring, metrics

I got database with several collections in micorservice, so there's controllers which works fine. But I need to collect statistics from servers, including database. There's a good query serverStats() which gives all the information about the server, but how can I pass it through app layers?

I made interface repository extended ReactiveCrudRepository using SomeModel class as a place holder and wrote one method like String getStatistics() with @Query annotation, but it doesn't work

```java
public interface MongoMonitoring extends ReactiveCrudRepository<SomeModel, String> {
    @Query("{ serverStatus: 1 }")
    String getStatus();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How you can execute the `{ serverStatus: 1 }` command, or how you can make that information available?

Comment: The question is how can I get result query from MongoDB without Object-like representation. I found the answer I used MongoTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoTemplate. The code like:

```java
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
Document result = this.mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ serverStatus: 1 }");
```

The document is from package org.bson.Document which is like JSON.